# Java Functional Interface chaining around conditions

Tags: java, function, functional-programming, chaining, functional-interface

Have been recently trying to toy around with functional interface chaining and I am trying to understand if the following is possible.

If I have an FI like this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface MyProcessor<T, R> {
    R process (T t);

    default MyProcessor<T, R> andThenProcess(MyProcessor<T, R> after) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(after);
        return (T t) -> { process(t); return after.process(t); };
    }
}
```

I am wondering if I can build the process chain around check logic...so the following is simple straightforward example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyProcessor<String, String> uprocessor = string -> string.toUpperCase();
    MyProcessor<String, String> lprocessor = string -> string.toLowerCase();
    MyProcessor<String, String> processor = lprocessor.andThenProcess(uprocessor);

    System.out.println(processor.process("Justin Skidmore"));

}
```

But I am trying to do something like the following and wondering if this is even reasonable:

```
MyProcessor<String, String> uprocessor = string -> string.toUpperCase();
MyProcessor<String, String> lprocessor = string -> string.toLowerCase();
MyProcessor<String, String> processor = lprocessor;

if (true) {
   processor.andThenDoThis(uprocessor);
}

System.out.println(processor.process("Justin"));
```

The above doesn't work and I kind of understand why but is there a proper approach that would get me to what I am trying to accomplish here. I have searched but alas have not come across a scenario or answer on this.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Does your code actually compile? I can't see how your `default` method is valid with two `return` statements one after the other. And I also can't understand what `R` ever represents in your interface declaration: the processor takes a value of type `T` and returns a value of type `T`, so is it actually necessary to declare `R`? Finally, unless this is homework, you really should just use the existing Java class `UnaryFunction<T>` which provides exactly the behaviour I *think* you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks I missed that return bit, updated. Yes it is homework of trying to sort of emulate what is there to better understand it. Yes it compiles and runs.

Comment: this still doesn't compile, take some time out to put this into an editor and frame the question with correct reproducible code to ask your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `andThenDoThis` method is returning a new instance, not modifying the existing one. Did you mean

```
processor = processor.andThenDoThis(uprocessor);
```

Comment: this is the answer, can't believe I missed that. thanks